# Why bind.apply(fn, arguments) omits the first argument when passed arguments object?

Tags: javascript

I bumped into an unexpected js behavior when I passed bind.apply() an arguments object as second argument, it seems like it omits the first argument as it executing the function.

```
function func(fn){
    console.log(arguments) // [ƒ, 4, 4]
    return fn.bind.apply(fn, arguments)
}


function add(a,b,c){
    console.log(arguments) // [4, 4]
    return b + c // c is undefined
}

let foo = func(add,4, 4)
foo() // NaN (expected 8)
```

Comment: So you're using `apply` to set `fn` as `this` for `bind`. It's quite unclear what you're trying to do. What do you expect `a`, `b` and `c` to be in `add`?

Comment: I would expect their values to be the same as were in func

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. Because `arguments` contains `fn`, that should be part of the arguments passed to `bind`. Interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) accepts one or more arguments

```js
(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

When you use [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply) with arguments `(fn, [fn, 4, 4])`, you are doing two things...

1. Binding the `Function.prototype.bind` `this` context to `fn`, and
2. Calling `bind(fn, 4, 4)`

Do you now see the problem? `bind(fn, 4, 4)` will create a new function, bound to `fn` for its `this` context and with default arguments `(4, 4)`.

---

If you really want `fn` to appear as the first argument to itself (which sounds like a bad idea to me), I find the spread operator much easier to understand

```js
function func(fn, ...args) {
  return fn.bind(fn, fn, ...args)
  //             ^   ^   ^
  //             |   |   |
  //             |   |   args #2, #3, ...
  //             |   arg #1
  //             this
}
```

Comment: @rafi depends if you want the function to use `this`. If you want to use `bind` to provide default arguments, you need to provide _something_ as the `thisArg`